# W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 9101219 9117278

Tags: mongodb, debian, docker

I am installing the `mongo` client and just now started to get the following error message

```
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 9101219 9117278
```

This is in response to the following `RUN` command in my `Dockerfile`.

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10 && \
    echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mongodb-org-shell
```

How ought I resolve this?

Comment: Able to give the whole `Dockefile` or at least the `FROM` and other dependencies to reproduce this?

Comment: Does this happen all the time? Or only once? It seems like an unsynchronized debian mirror server. `http.debian.net` is a loadbalancer, so each connection could end up on different backend mirror server.

Comment: The problem went away by itself.

Comment: Voting as off-topic since this question belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com or maybe http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: Oddly, I'm finding that running `apt-get update` fails with this error 100% of the time but if I run it twice consecutively, the second run succeeds.